# Im missing an output from MOTD, MTU and users from docker group

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

So, I'm writing a bash script that doesnt give me any output.

The script is:

a)  going to detect what operating system that is running
b) And know what package managers to use between APT, DNF and Pacman.

Further in the script it is:
a) going to choose the correct package manager to use when installing both Docker and Docker-Compose.

2. I have written down the MOTD function that should show a message on my ubuntu server.
3. Im creating a function that adds users to a docker group.
4. Configuring Docker Daemon that sets a specific MTU value to 1442 and logging.

The problem is that I dont get any output, otherwise from the MTU value that is actually 1442, that seems correct in my script.
Furhter i should get an empty line where i can get an input scenario to add a user that will be added in to a docker group.

```
#!/bin/bash


# This script will install Docker and Docker-Compose, configure the Docker daemon,
# and add specified users to the docker group.


# Define default values
MTU=1442
VERBOSE=false


# Function to detect operating system
detect_os() {
  if [ -f /etc/lsb-release ]; then
    os="ubuntu"
    package_manager="apt"
  elif [ -f /etc/redhat-release ]; then
    os="centos"
    package_manager="dnf"
  elif [ -f /etc/arch-release ]; then
    os="arch"
    package_manager="pacman"
  else
    echo "Error: Unable to detect operating system."
    exit 1
  fi
}


# Function to update MOTD
update_motd() {
  local motd_file="/etc/motd"
  echo "$1" > "$motd_file"
  echo "MOTD updated with message: $1"
}


# Function to add users to docker group
add_users() {
  local users="$1"
  local group="docker"
  for user in $users; do
    # Check if user exists
    if ! id "$user" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
      useradd "$user"
      echo "User $user created."
    fi
    # Add user to docker group
    usermod -aG "$group" "$user"
    echo "User $user added to $group group."
  done
}


# Function to install Docker and Docker-Compose
install_docker() {
  local package_manager="$1"
  local packages="docker docker-compose"
  case "$package_manager" in
    apt)
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install -y $packages
      ;;
    dnf)
      sudo dnf install -y $packages
      ;;
    pacman)
      sudo pacman -S --noconfirm $packages
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Error: Invalid package manager: $package_manager"
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
}


# Function to configure Docker daemon
configure_docker() {
  local mtu="$1"
  local config_file="/etc/docker/daemon.json"
  # Create config file if it does not exist
  if [ ! -f "$config_file" ]; then
    sudo touch "$config_file"
    sudo chmod 644 "$config_file"
  fi
  # Update MTU value in config file
  sudo sh -c "echo '{\"mtu\": $mtu}' > $config_file"
  echo "Docker daemon configured with MTU=$mtu."
}


# Parse command line argume
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
    --motd )
      MOTD="$2"
      shift 2
      ;;
    --users)
      USERS="$2"
      shift 2
      ;;
    --mtu)
      MTU="$2"
      shift 2
      ;;
  esac
done

echo "MOTD: $MOTD"
echo "USERS: $USERS"
echo "MTU: $MTU"
echo "Script is finish"
```

The output doesnt show me anything more than the MTU=1442, and missing the users and MOTD.

Im not sure if I was clear enough, but from my project i thought my script was correct, but probably I'm missing some logic any places in my script. The projects tasks are described above, but im not sure if im on the right way here

Would appreciate any suggestions for the way in my script :)

Comment: I see that you defined several functions but didn't call them to be run.

On the other hand, seems that it is intended to pass arguments (in particular order) to the script at run time, such as:

 `--motd <MOTD_VALUE>`  `--users <USERS_VALUE>` and `--mtu <MTU_VALUE>` if you need to override the `MTU=1442` value defined in the script.

Just curious if you have written this script from scratch?

Comment: Most of the script are from the scratch yes, my part is from myself but idk with my partner in school has. But it aint much help to get from class, so i was just wondering what is wrong with this script. 

MTU=1442 is correct output, but the problem is to get the other outputs.

Comment: Again please review my first comment.

I'd also suggest to take a few minutes to review and understand the correct usage of `functions` and function's `arguments` like described [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/bash-function#:~:text=A%20bash%20function%20is%20a%20method%20used%20in,how%20they%20work%2C%20and%20how%20to%20use%20them.) or from any other relevant resource.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full-fix of your script - since I'm sure you are not about to cheat on your project but want to understand and know why your script doesn't provide your expected output so you will be able to develop it on your own.

Here I'm pasting a small script that may help you better understand the basic usage of `functions` in `BASH`. Hope it will help .

```bash
#!/bin/bash

### Defining function - Functions are reusable code blocks in the script and can accept arguments while calling them.
# So each time we call an individual function later in the script we may pass different arguments to it (if needed).

my_function1(){
  echo "this is a function that doesn't expect any arguments."
  echo "End of 'my_function1'"
}

my_function2(){
  echo "this is a function that do expect an argument."
  echo "this function expects one argument to print/echo it."
  echo "Hello ${1}"  # <-- Numerical Variables ($1 $2 .. $N) are reserved variables in 'BASH' which values are assigned from the relevant argument(s) provided to them on script runtime and function runtime.
  echo "End of 'my_function2'"
}

my_function3(){
  echo "this is a function that expect one or more arguments."
  echo "this function print/echo all arguments passed to it."
  echo "Hi ${@}"
  echo "End of 'my_function3'"
}

### Calling the functions to execute their code - we may pass relevant argument(s) to them.
# This is done by using the function name - and any parameter/string added after the function name will be passed to it as the function's argument accordingly.

# Running the `my_function1` without providing any arguments - since it is not neccessary.
my_function1

# Print an empty line to seperate outputs
echo ""

# Running the `my_function2` passing it a name as argument. Ex. Vegard
my_function2  Vegard

# Print an empty line to seperate outputs
echo ""

# Running the `my_function3` passing it a `name` as first argument and a `LAST_NAME` as second argument. Ex.  Vegard YOUR_LASTNAME
my_function3  Vegard  YOUR_LASTNAME

# Print an empty line to seperate outputs
echo ""

### End of the script.
# Exitting the script with the `0` exit-code.
exit 0
```

#### Bonus Update #1

##### How to provide `arguments` to a `script` at run time:

You can provide arguments to the scripts almost in the same way as providing arguments to the functions.

Assuming the script file name is `script.sh`, it is located in our current working directory, and it is `executable`:

- NAME - as first argument.
- LAST_NAME - as second argument.

Run the script as follows:
`./script.sh  NAME  LAST_NAME`

#### Bonus Update #2

##### How to provide Dynamic `arguments` to a `function` from the script run time:

If you need to provide a dynamic argument for a function at runtime instead of having `hard-coded` argument(s) for that function, you may use the same
reserved numeric variables princip.

###### Simple example

- Consider you run your script providing some argument that can be change on every run.

`./script.sh firstarg secondarg "last arg"`
*Note: If a single argument contains **space** character should be quoted to avoid detecting it as separate arguments - same applies to providing arguments to funtions*

**Sum-up:** These arguments will can be called by `$1` `$2` .. `$<N>` variables accordingly within the Script anywhere out of the Functions code blocks.

- `${@}` or `${*}` will get all the provided arguments - google to find their difference.
- Consider you defined functions that works with one or more arguments.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

my_function(){
  # Since this $1 is defined in the function's block itself, it
  # will get its value from the argument provided to function
  # at run-time Not directly from the arguments provided to the Script!
  echo "Argument I got is: ${1}"
}

my_other_function(){
  # Printing the first three arguments provided to function
  # delimited by Collons.
  echo "Arguments I got are: ${1} : ${2} : ${3}"
}

another_function(){
  # $@ will get all the argument provided to function
  # at run-time  Not directly from the arguments provided to the Script!
  echo "All arguments got are: ${@}"
}

### Now at calling those functions
# Providing a static argument
my_function STATIC_ARGUMENT

# Passing the First argument provided to the script at run-time to the same function.
my_function "${1}"

# Passing the Three arguments provided to the script at run-time to this function.
my_other_function "${1}" "${2}" "${3}"

# Passing all the provided arguments of the script to this function at run-time.
another_function ${@}
```

##### Summery

The same numeric reserved variables that used to refer to the argument passed to the script can be passed to a function when calling it, and in the same manner the function's arguments can be referred from within the function block.

###### Caution

The behavior of a script that deals with any argument that will contain `space` or other `special` character may vary since the `Bash` threats them differently.